# What does ImportError: cannot import name 'number' from 'test' (E:\P-L\Atom\RPS.py\test.py) mean?

Tags: python-3.x, atom-editor, importerror

HEY I'VE BEEN WORKING ON A PROJECT AND I KEEP GETTING THIS ERROR

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\P-L\Atom\RPS.py\Location.py", line 2, in 
from test import number
ImportError: cannot import name 'number' from 'test' (E:\P-L\Atom\RPS.py\test.py)

THE CODE:

```
import phonenumbers
from test import number
from phonenumbers import geocoder
ch_nmber = phonenumbers.parse(number, "CH")
print(geocoder.description_for_number(ch_nmber, "en"))
```

THE CODE FROM THE test FILE :

```
number = "MYNUMBER"
```

WHY CAN'T I IMPORT IT?

Comment: Your test.py file and other python file are in same folder?

Comment: is it a .py file you are importing from?

Comment: YES AND YES I AM

Comment: I DID THE SAME THING IN PYCHARM AND IT WORKED 

IN ATOM I JUST GOT RID OF THE OTHER FILE AND 
JUST PASTED THE NUMBER HERE